# FitViewPort Android libGDX

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

How can I use this `ViewPort` to fit the screen to the many Android devices as I can? What's the best option?.

This is my game.

**GameScreen.java**

```
public class GameScreen extends AbstractScreen {
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture texture;
private Paddle Lpaddle, Rpaddle;
private Ball ball;
private BitmapFont font;
private int puntuacion, puntuacionMaxima;
private Preferences preferencias;
private Music music;
private Sound sonidoex;

public GameScreen(Main main) {
    super(main);
        preferencias = Gdx.app.getPreferences("PuntuacionAppPoints");   
        puntuacionMaxima = preferencias.getInteger("puntuacionMaxima");
        music =Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("bgmusic.mp3"));
        music.play();
        music.setVolume((float) 0.3);
        music.setLooping(true);
        sonidoex = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("explosion5.wav"));
}


public void show(){
    batch = main.getBatch();
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("spacebg.png"));

    Texture texturaBola = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bola.png"));
    ball = new Ball(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - texturaBola.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - texturaBola.getHeight() / 2);
    Texture texturaPala= new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("pala.png"));
    Lpaddle = new LeftPaddle(80, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 -texturaPala.getHeight() /2);
    Rpaddle = new RightPaddle(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() -100, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - texturaPala.getHeight() /2, ball);
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("pointsfont.tf.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("pointsfont.tf.png"), false);
    puntuacion = 0;


}

public void render(float delta){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    updatePuntuacion();
    Lpaddle.update();
    Rpaddle.update();
    ball.update(Lpaddle, Rpaddle);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture, 0, 0,texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
    ball.draw(batch);
    Lpaddle.draw(batch);
    Rpaddle.draw(batch);
    font.draw(batch, "Points: " + Integer.toString(puntuacion), Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4 ,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 5);
    font.draw(batch, "High score: " + Integer.toString(puntuacionMaxima),Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4 ,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 5);
    batch.end();
}

private void updatePuntuacion(){
    if(ball.getBordes().overlaps(Lpaddle.getBordes())) { 
        puntuacion = puntuacion + 1;
        if(puntuacion > puntuacionMaxima)
        puntuacionMaxima = puntuacion;

    }
    if(ball.getBordes().x <= 0) 
        sonidoex.play();

    if(ball.getBordes().x <= 0)
    puntuacion =0;

    if(ball.getBordes().x <=0)
        Gdx.input.vibrate(1000);

    if(ball.getBordes().x <=0)
        Screens.juego.setScreen(Screens.MAINSCREEN);

    ball.comprobarPosicionBola();
    }


public void hide(){
    font.dispose();
    texture.dispose();

}

@Override
public void dispose(){
    preferencias.putInteger("puntuacionMaxima", puntuacionMaxima);
    preferencias.flush();
}

public void resize(int width, int height){      
    float widthImage = texture.getWidth();
    float heightImage = texture.getHeight();
    float r = heightImage / widthImage;
    if(heightImage > height) { 
        heightImage = height;
        widthImage = heightImage / r;
    }
    if(widthImage > width) { 
        widthImage = width;
        heightImage = widthImage * r;
    }


}

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: Thank you, i know that, but i need more specific help from someone.

Comment: check my last post, there is my last try. I cant :(

Comment: I have 5 days with this issue

Comment: I already gave you answer on 2 of your questions. What exactly is your problem? Why you can't use fitviewports?

Comment: Do you have an example for my code? I cant understand the examples on the wiki. I do exactly what they said but just doesnt work. Thank you.